# Disabling html5 video autoplay in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, video, microsoft-edge, autoplay

I have a block of code for a video that doesn't autoplay in neither Chrome nor Firefox but still autoplays in Microsoft Edge:

```
<iframe width="688" height="315" src="myvid.mp4" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I think it's a feature/bug that only users can turn off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue in Edge. Can you use `<video>` tag to display the video? If so, the issue can be fixed perfectly.

Using an `<iframe>` to embed video is not a good practice. The correct way to display a video is using the [`<video>` tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp). You can refer to the code sample below, it won't auto play in Edge and other browsers:

```
<video width="320" height="176" controls>
    <source src="myvid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```